# Need help parsing xml array

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I need help parsing an XML file I have put in a PHP array. I have tried every way I can think of, but I keep getting errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Array
(
[question] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [prompt] => From whom did you purchase the property at 222333 PEACHTREE PLACE?
                [type] => purchased.property.from
                [answer] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => A VIRAY
                        [1] => JOE ANDERSON
                        [2] => ANDREW SCHWARZ
                        [3] => None of the above
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [prompt] => When did you purchase or lease your Ford Expedition?
                [type] => vehicle.purchase.date
                [answer] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => September 2004
                        [1] => December 2006
                        [2] => July 2010
                        [3] => None of the above
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [prompt] => What year is your Ford Expedition?
                [type] => vehicle.year
                [answer] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2004
                        [1] => 2005
                        [2] => 2006
                        [3] => None of the above
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

This is the array I am trying to parse. I need to get the prompt and the answer just as they appear. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you have, you say it's XML but you're showing a PHP array.

Comment: It is a php array that I made from an xml file. Sorry for the confusion. I have had a long day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you just need help iterating over the array?

```
foreach ($arr['question'] as $question) {
    echo "Prompt: {$question['prompt']}\n";
    foreach ($question['answer'] as $answer) {
        echo "- $answer\n";
    }
}
```